# kubernetes can not access other machine by ip from pod inside

Tags: kubernetes

kubernetes can't access other machine by ip from pod inside

```
kubectl exec dnsutils  -it /bin/bash
root@dnsutils:/# ping 10.116.197.60
PING 10.116.197.60 (10.116.197.60) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

but it works on machine

```
ping 10.116.197.60
PING 10.116.197.60 (10.116.197.60) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.854 ms
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.906 ms
...
```

and works on docker container

```
docker exec -it bind /bin/bash
root@0f356bf598c5:/# ping 10.116.197.60
PING 10.116.197.60 (10.116.197.60): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=1.172 ms
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.007 ms
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.260 ms
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.307 ms
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=1.118 ms
64 bytes from 10.116.197.60: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=1.023 ms
...
```

use tracerouter in pod

```
/ # traceroute -n -m 5 -q 4 -w 3 10.116.197.60
traceroute to 10.116.197.60 (10.116.197.60), 5 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  10.233.0.1  0.008 ms  0.005 ms  0.004 ms  0.004 ms
 2  *  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *  *
 4  *  *  *  *
 5  *  *  *  *

/ # ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0@if64: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 82:71:94:c7:fe:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.233.0.139/24 brd 10.233.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

look likes some error in 10.233.0.1
but i don't know why

kubernetes version: 1.20
network: flannel
mode: ipvs

after some test, ping other machine without snat.

```
09:20:24.997764 IP 10.233.0.156 > 10.116.197.60: ICMP echo request, id 149, seq 187, length 64
09:20:24.997888 IP 10.116.197.60 > 10.233.0.156: ICMP echo reply, id 149, seq 187, length 64
09:20:26.021795 IP 10.233.0.156 > 10.116.197.60: ICMP echo request, id 149, seq 188, length 64
09:20:26.021876 IP 10.116.197.60 > 10.233.0.156: ICMP echo reply, id 149, seq 188, length 64
09:20:27.045738 IP 10.233.0.156 > 10.116.197.60: ICMP echo request, id 149, seq 189, length 64
09:20:27.045825 IP 10.116.197.60 > 10.233.0.156: ICMP echo reply, id 149, seq 189, length 64
```

the ip `10.233.0.156` is ip of the pod, machine can not reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a iptables's rule to snat the pod ip

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.233.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

**`10.233.0.0/24` is value of `--pod-network-cidr`**

```
yum install iptables-services -y
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.233.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
service iptables save
systemctl enable iptables.service
```